# Sencha touch grid templatecolumn listener no working

Tags: button, grid, listener, sencha-touch-2.1

Hi i need i have button in my sencha touch grid. I need to fire the button event. Please c the code below

```
                           xtype: 'grid',
                           store : { xclass : 'JPM.store.MuatTurun.MuatTurun'}, 
                           title :'Muat Turun',
                           width: '100%',
                           itemHeight: 70,
                           columns: [

                               { 
                                  header: 'Name' , 
                                 itemId: 'mycolumn1',
                                  flex: 1 ,
                                  xtype: 'templatecolumn' ,
                                    tpl: '<button><div class="muatTurun">Muat Turun</div></button>',
                                   listeners: {
                                      click: function(){ 
                                        console.log('click'); 
                                      }, 
                                      dblclick: function(){ 
                                        console.log('dblclick'); 
                                      } ,
                                        itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {
                                           alert('working');
                                       },

                                    }
                               }

                           ] ,
                           plugins: [
                                       {
                                           type: 'gridpagingtoolbar'
                                       }
                                   ]                    



                       }
                       ]

            }
```

But the listener inside template column is not working. Any solutions?

Comment: looking for same, listeners are not getting supported. Help !!